# Starting form to appear before the next form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aHc7.png)I'm making a lottery simulator and I want a new form at the beginning that asks if your are 16 or older before you are taken to the main form. I'm using visual studio 2015 and coding in c#. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: umm..im not sure what you mean. I've already made the simulator and just need the starting form

Comment: for several reasons, first off you did not read the link on how to ask a question, and secondly it's a poorly written / posted question.. read this yourself and you tell us what you think, also you don't post code or show any effort . .

Comment: read `C# Basics Tutorial` there are a lot of free ones online

Comment: sounds like you should be able to figure out this simple solution, if you do not know how to create a simple form, then you need to go back or read `C# Basics Tutorial` focus on Forms Creation and Instantiation. you don't add images, you add actual code.. it's not how things work here Good luck

Comment: In your main form overwrite `OnShown()`. There open another form by calling `.ShowDialog()` on that new form. Check the return value for being OK to proceed. Otherwise call `Close()`.

Comment: Can you post the code? Especially the part in which the (main-)form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you double click the form that currently shows up first to get the form load method, then place your form you want to show up first within the method, it should display when the main form loads up and hide the first one. Just make it so No exits the environment.

```
 private void Lottery_Sim_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AgeVerificationForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```